# Plotly offline time series with multiple axis

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I have a plotly offline chart with datetime and single y axis,now I want to add one more line in y axis.

original code:

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode,plot
plot([Scatter(x=datetimefield,y=value1)],filename="plotly.html")
```

To add multiple I am tried to tweak the y parameter :

```
plot([Scatter(x=datecolumn,y=[value1,value2])],filename="plotly.html")
```

But this doesn't seems to be working.

x=datetime field is time series based

y=value1 & value 2 are two pandas columns

Note:- Two axis are in different datatype one is numeric other is percentage

How to tweak the y parameter in offline mode of plotly to have multiple axis.

Comment: Please format your code correctly

Comment: you can do this using multiple traces. For example refer: https://github.com/SayaliSonawane/Plotly_Offline_Python/tree/master/Scatterplot/Multi_trace%20Scatterplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution:

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode,plot
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Scatter(
x=df.datetimecolumn,
y=df.value1)

trace2 = go.Scatter(
x=df.datetimecolumn,
y=df.value2)

data = [trace1, trace2]

layout = go.Layout(
xaxis=dict(

    zeroline=True,
    showline=True,
    mirror='ticks',
    gridcolor='#bdbdbd',
    gridwidth=2,
    zerolinecolor='#969696',
    zerolinewidth=4,
    linecolor='#636363',
    linewidth=6
),
yaxis=dict(

    zeroline=True,
    showline=True,
    mirror='ticks',
    gridcolor='#bdbdbd',
    gridwidth=2,
    zerolinecolor='#969696',
    zerolinewidth=4,
    linecolor='#636363',
    linewidth=6
)
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot(fig)
```